# How does a protocol method set a variable in a class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols, xctest

I'm reading a Swift OOP book and I'm on a chapter about protocols.  I understand that a protocol is similar to a contract which has properties and methods that a class would adopt and implement.  After working on a `UITableView` tutorial, I noticed that the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol has a `numberOfSections()` method that returns an Integer.  This method also sets the `numberOfSections` variable in a `UITableView` instance.  This isn't clear to me how this is happening because I assumed that the `UITableView` class is separate from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol therefore wouldn't set any of its properties.  Here is the sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ItemListDataProvider: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate 
{        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
}
```

Here is the test that proves that the `UITableView` property is being set by the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol's method:

```
import XCTest
@testable import PassionProject

class ItemListDataProviderTests: XCTestCase 
{        
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func tests_NumberOfSectionsIsTwo(){

        let sut = ItemListDataProvider()
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.dataSource = sut
        tableView.delegate = sut
        let numberOfSections = tableView.numberOfSections
        XCTAssertEqual(numberOfSections, 2)
    }
}
```

I understand that we are blind to Apple's API but while trying to learn Swift OOP, I'd like to understand what is happening under the hood.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614924-numberofsections): *"UITableView gets the value in this property from its data source and caches it."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is setting the value. It is defined as getter property. So, this would be its closest definition.

```
    open var numberOfSections: Int { 
        get { 
             return datasource.numberOfSections
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Consider we are in UITableView Class and when you set the dataSource and delegate of TableView in your any controller class.For example

tableView.dataSource = yourControllerClassObject; 
tableView.delgate = yourControllerClassObject; 

Above code shows that you are passing your controller object to tableView Class and tableView Class holds your controller class object in it's protocol variable of "delegate and dataSource".

When you implement dataSource protocol method in your Controller Class,you are able to call those method from tableView class like below:

class tableView{

self.dataSource.numberOfSections(in tableView: self)

}

above numberOfSctions method returns an integer value of sections that we can store in any variable of class tableView like below.

class tableView{

var numberOfSections = self.dataSource.numberOfSections(in tableView: self)

}
```